# Random texture anti-aliasing/transparency issue in Android OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

I'm writing a game in native code and all graphics is done with OpenGL ES 2.0. I have written my own font rendering engine that uses font sprite atlas to render all text into a separate new texture using framebuffer. This way the actual text is done once and subsequent draw calls is for one texture only.

While this works like a charm the outcome is that some texts are beautifully rendered and others have shagged curves (all from the same anti-aliased sprite fonts). A code snippet is shown below. What could be causing this behaviour? I've tried to use highp precision (maybe wrongly?), but it didn't seem to have effect. However, when adding or removing letters (even the same) and thus making the final produced texture different size causes it sometimes to have shagged edges and sometimes to be smooth. Sprite font sheet anti-aliasing is made with alpha channel/transparency.

```
static const char *VERTEX_SHADER =
    "attribute vec4 aPosition;\n"
            "attribute vec2 aTexture;\n"
            "varying vec2 vTexture;\n"
            "uniform mat4 uProjection;\n"
            "void main() {\n"
            "   vTexture = aTexture;\n"
            "   gl_Position = uProjection * aPosition;\n"
            "}";

static const char *FRAGMENT_SHADER =
    "precision mediump float;"
            "uniform sampler2D uTexture;\n"
            "uniform vec3 uColor;\n"
            "varying vec2 vTexture;\n"
            "void main() {\n"
            "   vec4 tex = texture2D(uTexture, vTexture);\n"
            "   if (tex.a != 0.0f)"
            "       gl_FragColor = vec4(uColor, tex.a);\n"
            "   else\n"
            "       gl_FragColor = tex;\n"
            "}\n";

    ...CREATE AND COMPILE SHADERS...THEN:
aPosition = glGetAttribLocation(m_renderShaderProgram, "aPosition");
aTexture = glGetAttribLocation(m_renderShaderProgram, "aTexture");
uProjection = glGetUniformLocation(m_renderShaderProgram, "uProjection");
uTexture = glGetUniformLocation(m_renderShaderProgram, "uTexture");
uColor = glGetUniformLocation(m_renderShaderProgram, "uColor");    GLuint renderTexture;
GLuint renderFrameBuffer;
glGenTextures(1, &renderTexture);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, finalTextWidth, finalTextHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glGenFramebuffers(1, &renderFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, renderFrameBuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, renderTexture, 0);
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
glViewport(0, 0, finalTextWidth, finalTextHeight);
memset(m_projectionMatrix[0], 0, sizeof(m_projectionMatrix));
m_projectionMatrix[0][0] = 2.0f / (float)finalTextWidth;
m_projectionMatrix[1][1] = 2.0f / (float)finalTextHeight;
m_projectionMatrix[2][2] = -1.0f;
m_projectionMatrix[3][0] = -1.0f;
m_projectionMatrix[3][1] = -1.0f;
m_projectionMatrix[3][2] = 0.0f;
m_projectionMatrix[3][3] = 1.0f;
glUseProgram(m_renderShaderProgram);
glUniformMatrix4fv(uProjection, 1, GL_FALSE, m_projectionMatrix[0]);
glUniform1i(uTexture, 0);
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, <...ID TO THE FONT SPRITE SHEET TEXTURE...>);
...DRAW ACTUAL LETTERS AND THEN CLEAN UP...
```

Comment: If you solve your own problems, you should post the solution as an answer and accept that answer, instead of altering the question.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did that now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by filtering settings. Applying these solved the issue

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
```

However, there is still an important notice on the framebuffer usage, see [-SOLVED- Maximum texture creation/deletion in Android OpenGL ES 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43543631/maximum-texture-creation-deletion-in-android-opengl-es-2-0)